# Irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ invoking some fact of definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, radicals, irrational-numbers

Few months ago I tried to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational using some object/fact **from** (elementary, say us as simplest than is possible) **integral calculus.**

It is known that in some proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is used the quantities $\sqrt{2}\pm a$, where $a$ is an integer (see [1](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml)).

Again I would like to ask about it (as an open question and I hope that the question is anserwerable).

> **Question.** Is it possible to use any fact from integral calculus (you can to combine with the definition of Riemann integral, recurrence relations, calculation of areas, uses of the infinite...) to get a proof of the irrationaly of $\sqrt{2}$ (even if it is presented as more artificious than the ones that are in the literature)? **Many thanks.**

My last attempt was to write expressions as $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{x}}}dx=4(\sqrt{2}-1),$$
and (playing with this kind of integrals) defining the integer $4$ as $$\mathcal{J}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{x}}}dx$$
then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\mathcal{J}}\binom{\mathcal{J}}{k}\left(\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{\sqrt{\mathcal{J}}-\sqrt{x}}}dx\right)^k\cdot \mathcal{J}^{-k}=\mathcal{J}.$$

### References:

[1](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml) *[Square root of 2 is irrational](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/sq_root.shtml)*, Cut The Knot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider the integrals
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{P_n(2x-1)}{\sqrt{2-x}}\,dx $$
which by the generating function for Legendre polynomials fulfill
$$ I_n = \frac{2}{2n+1}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)^n = \frac{2}{2n+1}(A_n\sqrt{2}-B_n),\qquad A,B\in\mathbb{Z}^+.$$
They provide approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ as $\frac{B_n}{A_n}$, and the coefficients $A_n$, given by [A001653](https://oeis.org/A001653), fulfill the recurrence relation $A_{n+2}=6 A_{n+1}-A_n$, hence they behave like $\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}(3+2\sqrt{2})^n$ for large values of $n$. In particular

$$ \left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{B_n}{A_n}\right|=\left|\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{I_n}{A_n}\right|\leq \frac{C}{A_n^{3/2}} $$
holds for infinite values of $n$ and $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be a rational number.

This is not really different from showing $\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,2,\ldots]$, since the rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ found through $I_n$ are related to [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number) and to the convergents of such (infinite) continued fraction.

The argument above works also if applied to the sequence of rational approximations $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ got by applying Newton's method to the polynomial $x^2-2$, with starting point $x_0=\frac{3}{2}$, for instance.

Comment: What does $P_n$ stand for?

Comment: I generalized an aspect of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

As usual,
Jack D'Aurizio's answer
is quite good.

I will try to generalize
an aspect of his answer.

For a positive real $x$,
suppose there a sequence of rationals
$\frac{a_n}{b_n}$
with $b_n$ strictly increasing
such that
$|x-\frac{a_n}{b_n}|
\lt \frac1{b_n^{1+c}}
$
for all large enough $n$
for some $c > 0$.

Then $x$ is irrational
or
$x = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$
for all large enough $n$.

Proof.

Suppose $x$ is rational
so $x = \frac{r}{s}$
for some positive integers
$r$ and $s$.
Then
$|\frac{r}{s}-\frac{a_n}{b_n}|
\lt \frac1{b_n^{1+c}}
$.
Multiplying by
$sb_n$,
this becomes
$|rb_n-sa_n|
\lt \frac{s}{b_n^c}
$.

The left side of this is an integer.
If we choose 
$n$ large enough
so that
$\frac{s}{b_n^c}
\le 1$
(i.e.
$b_n
\ge s^{1/c}
$),
then the left side must be zero,
so $x = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$
for all large enough $n$.

In Jack's answer,
$\left|\sqrt{2}-\frac{B_n}{A_n}\right|
=\left|\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{I_n}{A_n}\right|
\ne 0$
with
$c = \frac12$,
so
$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: If for every $e>0$ there exist $a,b\in \Bbb Z $ such that $ 0<|x-a/b|<e/|b|$  then $x\not \in \Bbb Q.$... Because if $x=c/d$ with $c,d\in \Bbb Z$ then $0<|x-a/b|$ $<e/|b|\implies 0<|bc-ad|\in$ $ \Bbb Z\implies$ $ 1\leq |bc-ad|\implies$ $ (1/|d|)/|b|\leq |x-a/b|,$ so we must have $e\geq 1/|d|.$

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution, I'm going to take remarks in my notebook about the answer and your remarks.